# c# shorthand for if not null in property new

Tags: c#

I have a method like this :

```
public string GenerateJwtToken(User user, Transaction? transaction)
{
    // generate token that is valid for time from app.config
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
            new Claim(Constants.JWT_CLAIMS_USER_ID, user.Id.ToString()),

        }),
        IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Issuer = Constants.JWT_ISSUER,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(_appSettings.JwtTokenExpirationTime),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    // Some Stuff
}
```

Is it possible to add a *claim* if transaction is not null ? I'm looking for the equivalent of :

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
        new Claim(Constants.JWT_CLAIMS_USER_ID, user.Id.ToString()),
        HERE --> transaction != null ? new Claim(Constants.JWT_CLAIMS_TRANSACTION_GUID : /*DO NOTHING */, transaction.Guid.ToString()),
    }),
    IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Issuer = Constants.JWT_ISSUER,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(_appSettings.JwtTokenExpirationTime),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
```

It seems to be a simple question, but I don't know the answer...

Comment: On a side note, if the transaction is null then `transaction.Guid.ToString()` will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Not everything has to be shortened to a single line.

Create your list of `Claim` objects:

```
var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(Constants.JWT_CLAIMS_USER_ID, user.Id.ToString()) };
```

Conditionally append to it:

```
if (transaction != null)
    claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.JWT_CLAIMS_TRANSACTION_GUID));
```

Use the list:

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.ToArray()),
    //...
};
```